# Foreign key to subtype or super types?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm using SQL Server

and in this case i have the following tables:

- Restock: Foreign key to an R&D Staff member
- R&D_Staff: subtype from Staff
- Sales_Staff: subtype from Staff
- Shipping_Staff:  subtype from Staff
- Staff: supertype

Should the foreign key be pointing to `Staff` (Supertype) or to `R&D_Staff` (Subtype)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-phrasing, do you mean:

> don't allow Sales or Shipping staff values in restock?

Then the foreign key is from `Restock` to `R&D_Staff` to allow only values from RnD staff in the `Restock` table